# How do I make the print statement from this code stay in one line?

Tags: python

**How do I make the print statement from this code stay in one line?**

```
import time

bitcoin = 0

while 1 == 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"Bitcoin: {bitcoin}")
```

Comment: Do you mean the bitcoin value changes, and you want to just update the same printed out line?

Comment: Please elaborate and also what output you are expecting to help other people understand better

Comment: `bitcoin` never changes, so what is the effect of re-printing the same identical line?

Comment: @JohnGordon I think he intends to change the value later. You never know nowadays though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import time

bitcoin = 0

while 1 == 1:
  time.sleep(1)
  print(f"\r\xb[{2}KBitcoin: {bitcoin}",end='')
  bitcoin+=1
```

basically, `\r` is the escape code for carriage return, meaning it goes back to the start and writes over the previous line. `\x1b[{2}K` clears the line,(the previous bitcoin value). `end=''` means that print doesn't go down to a new line.

Another solution, if you know exactly what terminal coordinates you want the text is:

```py
import time

bitcoin = 0
x=10
y=0
def posprint(string,x=0,y=0):
  print('\u001b[s')
  print(f'\x1b[{y};{x}H\x1b[{2}K')
  print(f'\x1b[{y};{x}H',string)
  print('\u001b[u',end='')
while 1 == 1:
  time.sleep(1)
  posprint(f"Bitcoin: {bitcoin}",x,y)
```

`posprint` takes the coordinates you enter into it, and prints the text at those coordinates. I use ansi escape codes here to navigate to the position and clear the line before printing the string at that location.

Again, here `\x1b[{2}K` clears the line, but this time `\x1b[{y};{x}H` first travels to the `x` and `y` coordinates. Then, after clearing the line, the function goes back to the coordinates, and then finally prints the string.

The function also goes back to where the cursor was last. `\u001b[s` saves the cursor position and `\u001b[u` restores the position of the cursor.